# How to avoid elements in one array(ClickeditemType) getting pushed to another array(selectedclassnamesFirstLevel) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the below code

There is two arrays containing unique images as url but `Type` numbered 1  to 6 in each array

I selects 3 items from array `item1` and 3 items from array `item11`.  These 6 items are pushed to `mixarray1` with corresponding `Type` to identify it.

i have given `url` from mixarray1 to six boxes given in html into the class `pad` of each `hover panel` class img tag.

On each Click Each `hover panel` is flipped an image in behind are shown corresponding names of clicked `hover panel` is pushed to `selectedclassnamesFirstLevel`

imageurl corresponding to click is  stored in `link` for finding the `Type` of imageurl and stored in `Clickeditemslevel1`.

after `two clicks` the elements in `Clickeditemslevel1`(ie Types the digits labelled 1-6) are compared if two digits are equal then.....  The two classnames collected in `selectedclassnamesFirstLevel`(ie hover panel names) are flipped back.

**my problem is that**

after two clicks if when the `imageType` are different the two hover panel flips back.... after that when a two clicks contains imageType are same the hover panels stays there......
and comes the problem,
after that when two clicks contains different `imageTypes` the hover panels dont flips back

> when i checked in at that point the  array
>   `selectedclassnamesFirstLevel` which have the names of hover panels
>   have `ClickeditemType`...

**How to avoid this `ClickeditemType` digits coming in `selectedclassnamesFirstLevel` Array**

```js
var array2 = [];
var array21 = [];

var forpurchase = [];
var notes = [];
var itempurchase = [];
var curruspondingnotes = [];
var mixarray1 = [];
var clikeditemslevel1 = [];
var emptyarray = [];
var selectedclassnamesFirstLevel = [];
var clickcounter = 0;

var items1 = [{
    label: '38.jpg',
    url: "https://i.ibb.co/Rp7MZrj/38.jpg",
    type: '1'
  },
  {
    label: '55.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Fs7P75q/55.jpg',
    type: '2'
  },
  {
    label: '75.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/rwdV3mw/75.jpg',
    type: '3'
  },
  {
    label: '100.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/NsTJwMg/100.jpg',
    type: '4'
  },
  {
    label: '125.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/h707xz4/125.jpg',
    type: '5'
  },
  {
    label: '150.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/zPKQXCY/150.jpg',
    type: '6'
  }
];

var items11 = [{
    label: '38.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/xL7Pb80/t38.jpg',
    type: '1'
  },
  {
    label: '55.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Gd4sThr/t55.jpg',
    type: '2'
  },
  {
    label: '75.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/xgFyTqq/t75.jpg',
    type: '3'
  },
  {
    label: '100.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/3MNsCch/t100.jpg',
    type: '4'
  },
  {
    label: '125.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/4d2zr54/t125.jpg',
    type: '5'
  },
  {
    label: '150.jpg',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/Sy4CDm0/t150.jpg',
    type: '6'
  }
];


array2 = items1.slice();
array21 = items11.slice();

function rvalue() {

  for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    var itempurchase = array2[index];
    var curruspondingnotes = array21[index];


    try {

      forpurchase.push({
        label: itempurchase.url,
        type: itempurchase.type
      });
      notes.push({
        label: curruspondingnotes.url,
        type: curruspondingnotes.type
      });

      mixarray1.push({
        label: curruspondingnotes.url,
        type: curruspondingnotes.type
      });
      mixarray1.push({
        label: itempurchase.url,
        type: itempurchase.type
      })
    } catch (err) {}
  }
}

rvalue();


//----------------------------setting images to src--------------------------------

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  new1 = document.getElementById(i + 1);
  imagee = mixarray1[i].label;
  var path = imagee;
  $(new1).attr('src', path);
}
//new1.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + imagee + ')';


//----------------------flip function starts------------------------------------

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.hover').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flip');
    var k = $(this).attr('class');


    var fileNameIndex = k.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var filename = k.substr(fileNameIndex);
    var result0 = filename.slice(0, -5);

    selectedclassnamesFirstLevel.push(result0);

    console.log("result0 is" + result0);
    console.log("selectedclassnamesFirstLevel" + selectedclassnamesFirstLevel);
    console.log(selectedclassnamesFirstLevel);

    var takenpad = $(this).find('.pad');
    var imagcheck = $(takenpad).find('img');
    var link = imagcheck.first().attr("src");

    var fileNameIndexforsearch = link;
    var filenameurl = link.substr(fileNameIndexforsearch);
    let toSearch = 'filenameurl';
    clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
    let resultType = mixarray1.filter(obj => {
      return obj.label === filenameurl
    })
    let clickedtype = resultType[0].type;

    clikeditemslevel1.push(clickedtype);

    //--------------->Remove hoverpanel coming in clikeditemslevel1[] array --------------------------- 
    for (i = 0; i < clikeditemslevel1.length; i++) {
      if (clikeditemslevel1[i].length > 2) {
        clikeditemslevel1.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    console.log("!!!!!!!!!CLICKED ITEM TYPE ARRAY BELOW!!!!!!!!!");
    console.log(clikeditemslevel1);

    //--------------->Checking wether clicked two types are Not Equal--------------------------------------  

    if (typeof clikeditemslevel1[0] !== "undefined" && typeof clikeditemslevel1[1] !== "undefined" && clikeditemslevel1[0] != clikeditemslevel1[1]) {
      flipthisTypehoverpanel();
    }

    //--------------->Checking wether clicked two types Are Equal------------------------------------------      

    if (typeof clikeditemslevel1[0] !== "undefined" && typeof clikeditemslevel1[1] !== "undefined" && clikeditemslevel1[0] == clikeditemslevel1[1]) {
      selectedclassnamesFirstLevel = emptyarray;
      selectedclassnamesSecondLevel = emptyarray;

    }

    if (clickcounter == 2) {
      clikeditemslevel1 = emptyarray;
      while (clikeditemslevel1.length > 0) {
        clikeditemslevel1.pop();
      }
      clickcounter = 0;

    }

  });
});



function flipthisTypehoverpanel() {




  firstpanel = selectedclassnamesFirstLevel[0];
  secondpanel = selectedclassnamesFirstLevel[1];


  m = firstpanel.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
  n = secondpanel.replace(/\s+/g, '.');

  m = "." + m;
  n = "." + n;

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(m).toggleClass('flip');
    $(n).toggleClass('flip');
  }, 800);

  var emptyarray = [];
  selectedclassnamesFirstLevel = emptyarray;
  selectedclassnamesSecondLevel = emptyarray;
  console.log(selectedclassnamesFirstLevel);

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #78D6CC !important;
}

.panel1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  left: 20vw;
  bottom: 80vh;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */


/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel1 .front {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel1.flip .front {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel1 .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel1.flip .back {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}


/*-------------------------------second box--------------------*/

.panel2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  left: 38vw;
  bottom: 80vh;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */


/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel2 .front2 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel2.flip .front2 {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel2 .back2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel2.flip .back2 {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}


/*-------------------------------third box--------------------*/

.panel3 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  left: 55vw;
  bottom: 80vh;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */


/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel3 .front3 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel3.flip .front3 {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel3 .back3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel3.flip .back3 {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}


/*-------------------------------fourth box--------------------*/

.panel4 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  left: 20vw;
  bottom: 57vh;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */


/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel4 .front4 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel4.flip .front4 {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel4 .back4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel4.flip .back4 {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}


/*-------------------------------fifth box--------------------*/

.panel5 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  left: 38vw;
  bottom: 57vh;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */


/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel5 .front5 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel5.flip .front5 {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel5 .back5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel5.flip .back5 {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}

.panel6 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vh;
  left: 55vw;
  bottom: 57vh;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: .8em;
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
  -moz-perspective: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/* -- make sure to declare a default for every property that you want animated -- */


/* -- general styles, including Y axis rotation -- */

.panel6 .front6 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel6.flip .front6 {
  z-index: 900;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel6 .back6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 800;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* -- transition is the magic sauce for animation -- */
  -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel6.flip .back6 {
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover panel1" style="border:px solid blue;">
  <div class="front">
    <div class="top" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <p></p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <div class="pad" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <img src="" alt="" id="1" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:px solid black; " />

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hover panel2" style="border:px solid blue;">
  <div class="front2">
    <div class="top" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back2">
    <div class="pad" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <img src="" alt="" id="2" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hover panel3" style="border:px solid blue;">
  <div class="front3">
    <div class="top" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back3">
    <div class="pad" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <img src="" alt="" id="3" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hover panel4" style="border:px solid blue;">
  <div class="front4">
    <div class="top" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back4">
    <div class="pad" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <img src="" alt="" id="4" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hover panel5" style="border:px solid blue;">
  <div class="front5">
    <div class="top" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back5">
    <div class="pad" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <img src="" alt="" id="5" style="width:100%; height:100%; " />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hover panel6" style="border:px solid blue;">
  <div class="front6">
    <div class="top" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back6">
    <div class="pad" style="border:px solid red; width:100%; height:100%;">
      <img src="" alt="" id="6" style="width:100%; height:100%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```